# Shell script - Bump version automatically git

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell, makefile

I've the following command which I want to execute **with one command** via 'makefile' how can I do it ?

```
1. git tag -a v0.0.1 -m "new release"
2. git push origin v0.0.1
```

Now I've created something for start

```
git:
    git add .
    git commit -m "$m"
    git push origin master
```

Now I've two issue, how to resolve the version e.g.
Here is v0.0.1 but for each new release I need to bump it like first is 
v0.0.1 and the next release should be v0.0.2, can it be done somehow **automatically** (maybe have some counter...)? if not maybe add it as parameter to one command

1. git tag -a **v0.0.1** -m "new release"
2. git push origin **v0.0.1**

**update**

There is answer which looks good  with the following

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | awk -F. '{$NF+=1; OFS="."; print $0}'
```

but How should I combine it with ?

1. git tag -a **v0.0.1** -m "new release"
2. git push origin **v0.0.1**

**update 2**

When I try the following as suggest in Kevin answer I got error:

.PHONY: git

VERSION=`git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | awk -F. '{$NF+=1; OFS="."; print $0}'`

```
git:
    git add .
    git commit -m "$m"
    git push origin master
    git tag -a $(VERSION) -m "new release"
    git push origin $(VERSION)
```

**The error is:** `fatal: tag 'ERSION' already exists`
it seems that the bump of not working and it somehow remove the `v` from version

I did another check, remove the repo and start it from scratch manually for the first release `0.0.1` now I did change in one file and run the script , the version should now be `0.0.2` if it success, but no Im getting error `fatal: tag 'v0.0.1' already exists` which explain that the **bump is not working**, any idea why ?

I guess it's related to this code  `'{$NF+=1; OFS="."; print $0}'

Comment: You can take the version as a parameter the same way you're doing with the message.

Comment: `git describe --tags`returns the latest tag. You can add this to a var and increase the number by 1 to create a new tag.

Comment: @JoaoVitorino - thanks, how should I combine it with `git tag -a v0.0.1 -m "new release"` in the code ?

Comment: I wrote this script that automates a lot of pre-release steps, including bump version functionality, hope it helps anyone who wants to perform these kind of steps automatically: https://github.com/jv-k/bump-version.sh

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using the last pushed tag you could automatically increment your version number:

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | awk -F. '{OFS="."; $NF+=1; print $0}'
```

Keep in mind that you store it in a variable and use it to `tag` and `push`:

```
VERSION=`git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | awk -F. '{OFS="."; $NF+=1; print $0}'`
git tag -a $VERSION -m "new release"
git push origin $VERSION
```

---

## Explanation:

**git describe** - Show the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit

**--tags** - Enables matching a lightweight (non-annotated) tag.

**--abbrev=0** - Will suppress long format, only showing the closest tag.

---

**awk -F.** - Process pattern using "." as a delimiter

**'{OFS="."; $NF+=1; print $0}'** - only increment last number and join with "."

---

[makefile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kevinsandow/auto-increment/master/makefile):

```
.PHONY: git

git:
    $(eval VERSION=$(shell git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | awk -F. '{OFS="."; $$NF+=1; print $0}'))
    git add .
    git commit -m "$m"
    git push origin master
    git tag -a $(VERSION) -m "new release"
    git push origin $(VERSION)
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot for this 1+ , im trying it now ...btw what happen if 0.0.9 to 0.1.0 ?

Comment: 0.0.9 would simply go to 0.0.10, incrementing major or minor version would still have to be done manually

Comment: Thanks, last question can you update the answer how should I combine it with `git tag -a v0.0.1 -m "new release"`  and `git push origin v0.0.1` just sample of  the script I put in the question with the combination of your answer

Comment: HI Kevin, thanks I've tried it and it seems that someting went wrong , when I put this command  `git describe --tags` in the CLI after I use the code above im getting `ersion` , before I was getting `0.0.9 `, any idea if there is something wrong with `awk -F. '{$NF+=1; OFS="."; print $0}'` the increase of the version ?

Comment: when I look at the output of the command (`git tag -a $VERSION -m "new release"`)i see - `git tag -a ERSION -m "new release"` any idea ?

Comment: Inside a makefile accessing to environment variables ist done via `$(VAR)`

Comment: Thanks i've try exactly the makefile you provide in the answer and I got error `git tag -a `git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | awk -F. '{F+=1; OFS="."; print }'` -m "new release"
`fatal: tag 'ERSION' already exists`
`

Comment: Does it working in your end ? I didnt change anything from your makefile in the answer you provided...can you please check ?

Comment: I execute it with: `make git m="new release"`

Comment: I have to replace spaces with one tab, but then it's working. I'm calling it with `make m="Message" git` and using GNU Make 3.81 - dunno if that's important.

Comment: I've tried also with make `m="Message" git ` and I got the same error , any other idea what it could be, strange that this is working on your end and mine not...

Comment: I did another check, remove the repo and start it from scratch manually for the first release `0.0.1` now I did change in one file and run the script , the version should now be `0.0.2` if it success, but no Im getting error `fatal: tag 'v0.0.1' already exists` which explain that the bump is not working, any idea why ?

Comment: makefiles have their own issues with environment variables, updated it with link to demo repo https://github.com/KevinBusse/auto-incrrement

Comment: Thanks it's working :) does it work also for 0.0.9 to 0.0.10?

Comment: Give it a try, ;-)

Comment: I discovered that newer versions of awk do not work. Both [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk)  and the [20180827 version of awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk) do not print the periods in the output. For instance, `v0.0.3` gets bumped to `v0 0 4`. I found that switching the order, so that it is `awk -F. '{OFS="."; $NF+=1; print $0}'` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Kevin Sandow's answer, find a more elaborate shell script below

latest version : https://gist.github.com/acucchieri/69bc649abde55315fe74bb68be82e0c8

```
#!/bin/bash

# The bump is performed only on the "main" or "master" branch unless a branch is specified with the -b argument
# Example :
#    bump-version -b staging


# Check that HEAD is not detached
DETACHED=`git branch --show-current | wc -l`
if [ $DETACHED -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "HEAD is detached. Please fix it before."
    exit 1
fi

BUILD_BRANCH=''

# Check if a branch was passed as an argument
while getopts "b:" option
do
    case $option in
        b)
            BUILD_BRANCH=$OPTARG
            ;;
    esac
done

# Determines the build branch ("main" or "master") if no branch was passed as an argument
if [ -z "$BUILD_BRANCH" ]; then
    if [ `git rev-parse --verify main 2>/dev/null` ]
    then
        BUILD_BRANCH='main'
    else
        if [ `git rev-parse --verify master 2>/dev/null` ]
        then
            BUILD_BRANCH='master'
        else
            echo "Unable to find \"main\" or \"master\" branch. Please use -b arg"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
fi

# Check that local is not behind origin
git fetch 2>/dev/null
if [ "$(git rev-list --count HEAD..$BUILD_BRANCH)" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Local is behind Origin. Please run git pull first."
    exit 1
fi

# Guess the next tag
if [[ "$(git tag --merged $BUILD_BRANCH)" ]]; then
    # increment the last tag
    NEXT_TAG=`git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | awk -F. '{OFS="."; $NF+=1; print $0}'`
else
    # there is no tag yet
    NEXT_TAG='0.1.0'
fi

# Ask for next tag
SEMVER_REGEX="^[vV]?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\\-[0-9A-Za-z-]+(\\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*)?(\\+[0-9A-Za-z-]+(\\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*)?$"
SEMVER_VALID=false
while [[ $SEMVER_VALID == false ]]
do
    read -p "Next tag [$NEXT_TAG]: " TAG
    # empty answer
    if [ -z "$TAG" ]; then
        # set guessed tag
        TAG=$NEXT_TAG
    fi
    # semver validation
    if [[ "$TAG" =~ $SEMVER_REGEX ]]; then
        SEMVER_VALID=true
    else
        echo 'Tag must match the semver scheme X.Y.Z[-PRERELEASE][+BUILD]. See https://semver.org/'
    fi
done

# Release message
if [[ $TAG =~ ^[v] ]]; then
    # remove "v" letter
    MESSAGE="release ${TAG:1:${#TAG}-1}"
else
    MESSAGE="release $TAG"
fi

# Checks if a commit is needed
if [ -n "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then
    git add -A .
    git commit -am "bump version"
fi

git tag -a "$TAG" -m "$MESSAGE"

# Ask to push new release
read -p "Push new release (Y/n)? [Y]:" -r
REPLY=${REPLY:-Y}
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[YyOo]$  ]]; then
  git push origin $BUILD_BRANCH --follow-tags
fi

exit 0
```